# githook doing actions on push based on working tree

Tags: git, githooks

I want to write a githook that, when the remote repository receives a push, reads information from the repositories working tree and performs actions based on the data it can find. If anything breaks during this hook, the push should be rejected! This would work on a non-bare repository only, of course.

I found the `update` hook to be quite suitable in regards of the time at which it is called. The only problem that I have now is that I can not checkout the newest ref from the `update` hook because it has not been integrated yet.

```
#!/bin/sh
# .git/hooks/update
refname="$1"
if [ "$refname" == "refs/heads/master" ]; then
    newrev="$3"
    git checkout "$newrev"
    # ... read from the tree and perform additional actions
fi
```

I (strangely) get this error message:

```
remote: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
remote:         somefile
```

If I understand the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) correctly, `post-update` would allow me to do the checkout, but will *not* allow me to reject the push. Is there a way to do it?

---

Update: I just tried to use `post-update` and run `git -C .. checkout master` from it, but I get

```
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
```

Even if I pass the full path to the non-bare remote repository, it says that it is not a git repository. Why is that? Does Git prevent operating on a non-bare basis inside a hook?

Update: Nevermind, I found it out. Git will always use `GIT_DIR` if it is set (even when it's empty). **The original question is still open**

```
# Procedure that will allow us to use git on a non-bare
# basis. If GIT_DIR is set, git will always use this directory
# instead of any other (cwd or passed via git -C ...)
git()
{
    unset GIT_DIR
    env git $*
}
```

---

Update: It seems like you can already checkout the `$newrev` although it has not been integrated already. This will create a detached HEAD unfortunately, but it gives you the right data into the working tree.

Comment: Why would you want to checkout the new ref ? I have fixed a similar thing with my update hook. Check if it answers your query.
https://github.com/Miyurz/scripts/blob/master/Git_Infrastructure_Scripts/git_hooks/update

Comment: @MayurNagekar I need to read from a file that is received by the push. To be more precise, whenever the master branch gets updated, I want to re-initialize a virtualenv and install all packages that are listed in the `requirements.txt` of the master's latest commit. -- Thanks for your file, I'll try to examine it. Having started to use shell script today, it's still hard for me to figure the semantics of some portions.

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you are interested in is the `requirements.txt` file you don't need to check out the full working directory.  You can instead just dump that one file out directly into your hook

```
git cat-file -p ${newrev}:<path>/requirementstxt
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that's neat! Unfortunatly it won't be sufficient as the push should automatically deploy the whole web application. Basically like Heroku Apps

Comment: Are you saying the checked out working directory *is* the deployed directory?  Because if it isn't you just read in requirements.txt and the `git cat-file` whatever you want to deploy to wherever you need to deploy it.

Comment: Exactly, the checked out directory is the deployed directory. Or to be precise, that is what I want to achieve. When the push is received, it should checkout the newest revision and do the deployment. Ideally, the push should be rejected if the deployment fails (installing dependencies, starting servers, ...)

Comment: Gotcha.  Do you still have a question?  i can't tell from your original post.

Comment: Yes. How to do it? Checking out the most pushed working copy on `update`. And what can't you tell from my original post? :)

Comment: It's got so many edits/updates I can't tell what the exact question is anymore.  You just need to set GIT_DIR and do a `git checkout` ?